# How to show the saved lookup value on the field saving the record?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lookup

When i search any value from lookup and click on save on backend record is created but after refresh the page of lwc component the value is removed. I want that value will be present in the field.

HTML

```html
<template>
    <div class="slds-form-element" onmouseleave={toggleResult}  data-source="lookupContainer">      
        <div class="slds-combobox_container slds-has-selection">
          <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="combobox-id-1">{label}</label>
          <div class="lookupInputContainer slds-combobox slds-dropdown-trigger slds-dropdown-trigger_click" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="listbox" role="combobox"> 
           <div class="slds-combobox__form-element slds-input-has-icon slds-input-has-icon_left-right" role="none">
              <div class="searchBoxWrapper slds-show">
                <!--Lookup Input Field-->
                <lightning-input                   
                   type="search"
                   data-source="searchInputField"
                   onclick={toggleResult}
                   onchange={handleKeyChange}
                   is-loading={isSearchLoading}
                   value={searchKey}
                   variant="label-hidden"
                   placeholder={placeholder}
               ></lightning-input>  
              </div>
              
            <!--Lookup Selected record pill container start-->  
            <div class="pillDiv slds-hide">        
              <span class="slds-icon_container slds-combobox__input-entity-icon">
                <lightning-icon icon-name={iconName} size="x-small" alternative-text="icon"></lightning-icon>  
              </span>
              <input type="text"
                     id="combobox-id-1"
                     value={selectedRecord.Name}       
                     class="slds-input slds-combobox__input slds-combobox__input-value"
                     readonly
                     />
              <button class="slds-button slds-button_icon slds-input__icon slds-input__icon_right" title="Remove selected option">
              <lightning-icon icon-name="utility:close" size="x-small" alternative-text="close icon" onclick={handleRemove}></lightning-icon> 
             </button>
            </div>  
            </div>
        
            <!-- lookup search result part start-->
            <div style="margin-top:0px" id="listbox-id-5" class="slds-dropdown slds-dropdown_length-with-icon-7 slds-dropdown_fluid" role="listbox">
              <ul class="slds-listbox slds-listbox_vertical" role="presentation">
                <template for:each={lstResult} for:item="obj">
                <li key={obj.Id} role="presentation" class="slds-listbox__item">
                  <div data-recid={obj.Id} onclick={handelSelectedRecord} class="slds-media slds-listbox__option slds-listbox__option_entity slds-listbox__option_has-meta" role="option">
                    <span style="pointer-events: none;" class="slds-media__figure slds-listbox__option-icon" >
                      <span class="slds-icon_container" >
                          <lightning-icon icon-name={iconName} size="small" alternative-text="icon" ></lightning-icon>  
                      </span>
                    </span>
                    <span style="pointer-events: none;" class="slds-media__body" >
                      <span  class="slds-listbox__option-text slds-listbox__option-text_entity">{obj.Name}</span>
                    </span>
                  </div>
                </li>
                </template>
                <!--ERROR msg, if there is no records..-->
                <template if:false={hasRecords}>
                  <li class="slds-listbox__item" style="text-align: center; font-weight: bold;">No Records Found....</li>
                </template>
              </ul>
             
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button class="slds-button slds-modal__close slds-button_icon-inverse" onclick={submitButton}>
            Save
      </button>
  </template>
```

JS

```js
import { LightningElement,api,wire} from 'lwc';
import fetchLookupData from '@salesforce/apex/CustomLookupLwcController.fetchLookupData';
import insertRecord from '@salesforce/apex/CustomLookupLwcController.insertRecord';
import fetchDefaultRecord from '@salesforce/apex/CustomLookupLwcController.fetchDefaultRecord';

export default class LookupComppnent extends LightningElement {
        // public properties with initial default values 
        @api label = 'custom lookup label';
        @api placeholder = 'search...'; 
        @api iconName = 'standard:account';
        @api sObjectApiName = 'SIC__c';
        @api defaultRecordId = '';
        objId;
        // private properties 
        lstResult = []; // to store list of returned records   
        hasRecords = true; 
        searchKey=''; // to store input field value    
        isSearchLoading = false; // to control loading spinner  
        delayTimeout;
        selectedRecord = {}; // to store selected lookup record in object formate 
       // initial function to populate default selected lookup record if defaultRecordId provided  
        
        // wire function property to fetch search record based on user input
        @wire(fetchLookupData, { searchKey: '$searchKey' , sObjectApiName : '$sObjectApiName' })
         searchResult(value) {
            const { data, error } = value; // destructure the provisioned value
            this.isSearchLoading = false;
            if (data) {
                 this.hasRecords = data.length == 0 ? false : true; 
                 this.lstResult = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data)); 
             }
            else if (error) {
                console.log('(error---> ' + JSON.stringify(error));
             }
        };
           
      // update searchKey property on input field change  
        handleKeyChange(event) {
            // Debouncing this method: Do not update the reactive property as long as this function is
            // being called within a delay of DELAY. This is to avoid a very large number of Apex method calls.
            this.isSearchLoading = true;
            window.clearTimeout(this.delayTimeout);
            const searchKey = event.target.value;
            this.delayTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
            this.searchKey = searchKey;
            }, DELAY);
        }
        // method to toggle lookup result section on UI 
        toggleResult(event){
            const lookupInputContainer = this.template.querySelector('.lookupInputContainer');
            const clsList = lookupInputContainer.classList;
            const whichEvent = event.target.getAttribute('data-source');
            switch(whichEvent) {
                case 'searchInputField':
                    clsList.add('slds-is-open');
                   break;
                case 'lookupContainer':
                    clsList.remove('slds-is-open');    
                break;                    
               }
        }
       // method to clear selected lookup record  
       handleRemove(){
        this.searchKey = '';    
        this.selectedRecord = {};
        this.lookupUpdatehandler(undefined); // update value on parent component as well from helper function 
        
        // remove selected pill and display input field again 
        const searchBoxWrapper = this.template.querySelector('.searchBoxWrapper');
         searchBoxWrapper.classList.remove('slds-hide');
         searchBoxWrapper.classList.add('slds-show');
         const pillDiv = this.template.querySelector('.pillDiv');
         pillDiv.classList.remove('slds-show');
         pillDiv.classList.add('slds-hide');
      }
      // method to update selected record from search result 
    handelSelectedRecord(event){   
          this.objId = event.target.getAttribute('data-recid'); // get selected record Id 
          console.log('id = '+this.objId);
         this.selectedRecord = this.lstResult.find(data => data.Id === this.objId); // find selected record from list 
         this.lookupUpdatehandler(this.selectedRecord); // update value on parent component as well from helper function 
         this.handelSelectRecordHelper(); // helper function to show/hide lookup result container on UI
    }
    /*COMMON HELPER METHOD STARTED*/
    handelSelectRecordHelper(){
        this.template.querySelector('.lookupInputContainer').classList.remove('slds-is-open');
         const searchBoxWrapper = this.template.querySelector('.searchBoxWrapper');
         searchBoxWrapper.classList.remove('slds-show');
         searchBoxWrapper.classList.add('slds-hide');
         const pillDiv = this.template.querySelector('.pillDiv');
         pillDiv.classList.remove('slds-hide');
         pillDiv.classList.add('slds-show');     
    }
    // send selected lookup record to parent component using custom event
    lookupUpdatehandler(value){    
        const oEvent = new CustomEvent('lookupupdate',
        {
            'detail': {selectedRecord: value}
            
        }
        
    );
    this.dispatchEvent(oEvent);
    }

    submitButton(event)
    {
        console.log('submit');
        const fields = { SIC_Code__c:this.objId}
        console.log('fields '+fields);

        insertRecord({sic: fields})
        .then(result=>{
            let res=result;
            console.log('succeess');
        })
    }
    
}
```

[image]